# How to catch image from python and insert it to word document?

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a function that loops through a list of words and writes those words on images, I can't figure out how those images can be inserted to word file. Any help is appreciated, thank you

I'm expecting a word file with all the images edited by the python code

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.